# Vaadin 24 dynamically changing style for Grid rows not working

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I want to change the text color for rows in my Grid, when a certain flag (archived) is set in the record. For that I followed the documentation in (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid#part-name-generator).

My code so far:

```java
    private final Grid<JobState> grid = new Grid<>(JobState.class, false);
    // add some columns
    grid.setPartNameGenerator(jobState -> {
       if(jobState.isArchived()) {
            return "archive";
       }
       return null;
   });
```

```css
vaadin-grid.styling::part(archive) {
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

The CSS file is located within an own theme, which as such works (I can change global settings there etc.).
A breakpoint within the PartGenerator verifies that it works as expected.
Only the selected part never takes any effect on the frontend.

My Vaadin version is 24.3.5.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found what I was missing:

```java
grid.addClassName("styling");
```

This is necessary to include the "styling" class of the css for this grid.
I overlooked that in the example.